# How to remove runtime error pointed out by online judges in several JAVA programs

Tags: java

I am getting NZEC repeatedly for a few programs when submitting my solutions to online judges like SPOJ and Codechef. I am noticing this behavior in programs that contain more than 1 function and classes.

Can someone please suggest where I am going wrong?

Question: https://www.codechef.com/problems/FIRESC/

My Answer: https://www.codechef.com/viewsolution/16564688

Please make the changes to the program and try it out!

Any help would be most appreciated!

Comment: Do they tell you what the error is or what line it's on, or what the input they are using is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under "Constraints", it says:

> 1 ≤ N ≤ 100000 (10^5)
>   0 ≤ M ≤ 100000 (10^5)

And your code has this line:

```
f.adj=new int[f.n][f.n];
```

But if N is 100000, you're attempting to create an array with *one hundred million* ints.  When I tried it, I got an OutOfMemoryError when it tried to create the array.

You're going to have to change the way you calculate the answer to not use such a potentially large array.

Comment: I implemented adjacency list for the question, and got rid of the NZEC!!
Thanks a lot for that tip!

The code works perfectly on my system, but I am still getting a WA. Can you please help me out!

New Answer: [https://www.codechef.com/viewsolution/16565151]

Comment: Does WA mean Wrong Answer (as in, there's no longer an exception, but the output is wrong)?

Comment: Just got it correct now. Can't thank you enough for your help!

Comment: Awesome, glad to hear it.

Answer (score 1):

The `f.adj=new int[f.n][f.n];` initialization may have resulted in an error if N is relatively large. N and M elements of [0, 100000] and [1, 100000] respectively, a worst case scenario would see well over 37 GB required.

Also, an error is just as likely for example, to have occurred in failing to check that the input is valid; `t=sc.nextInt();`would throw an InputMismatchException if the input is not an integer. Not knowing much about how the program is executed and the actual error itself makes it tedious to diagnose.

As a side note, naming variables with helpful names is a great way of automatic documentation

Comment: I implemented adjacency list for the question, and got rid of the NZEC!! Thanks a lot for that tip! The code works perfectly on my system, but I am still getting a WA. Can you please help me out! My new Answer: [codechef.com/viewsolution/16565151]

Comment: You could start with handling the potential for MismatchExceptions if you are not sure if the input will be integers only.

Comment: Thanks, got it correct now!. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: What was the issue?